# Flux: return values from AJAX to the component

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm working on simple Flux+Reactjs app, in my store I have:

```
var ProfileStore = merge(EventEmitter.prototype, {
/**
   * Get the entire collection of Profiles.
   * @return {object}
   */
  getAll: function() {
    //ajax call to mongolab
    var url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/bar/collections/profiles?apiKey=foo-"
    var jsPromise = Promise.resolve($.ajax(url));
    jsPromise.then(function(response) {
        return response;
    });

  },

  emitChange: function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  /**
   * @param {function} callback
   */
  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  /**
   * @param {function} callback
   */
  removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
});
```

and then in my component I have:

```
var ProfileApp = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            allProfiles: ProfileStore.getAll()
        };
    },

});
```

When I console.log() in the getAll() function I can see the results, but nothing is being passed to my component, any pointers on how I can fix this?

Comment: Making asynchronous calls from within your stores isn't always the best solution as it makes it harder to reason about what's happening with your state, as you've noticed. I'd recommend reading the following post which describes a better way of handling your asynchronous request with flux: http://www.code-experience.com/async-requests-with-react-js-and-flux-revisited/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have pointed out the problems in your code related to promises.  However, another issue with what you're trying to do in the store is that you're trying to handle the response directly, rather than dispatching a new action.

In Flux, data should always originate with an action.  The function `getAll()` should merely return the locally stored `allProfiles`, similar to what andrewkshim suggested, but without the XHR.

Instead, break what you're trying to do into two actions with the following types:

`PROFILES_REQUEST_GET` : this is created by the user clicking a button, or whatever is causing the request to be made -- it kicks off a XHR request.

`PROFILES_REQUEST_SUCCESS` : this is the action created by the XHR's success callback.  This action contains the new data, and the store can populate its `allProfiles` accordingly.

Comment: Is the code above how you're trying to initialize your app?  If so, just call for the data in the bootstrap module, and then create an action in the success callback, similar to what I've described in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you mention that in Flux, data should always originate with an action, in my case I want to load the profiles immediately the component renders, not in response to an action, would the approach be the same as you've suggested above?

Comment: Rewrote the app and followed the code for the flux-chat app here are the gists https://gist.github.com/johnwesonga/316b26760e2be043bbb1 works quite well now

Answer (score 1):

The setup with Flux requires you to think differently about the way the data is flowing. What you can do is to set up your store so that is holds a reference to `allProfiles`, which is `undefined` (or `null` or any specified "empty" value you'd prefer) at first then updated whenever `getAll()` is called:

```
var allProfiles;  // the reference to your profile data

var ProfileStore = merge(EventEmitter.prototype, {

  getAll: function() {
    var thisStore = this;

    var url = "YOUR MONGO URL"
    var jsPromise = Promise.resolve($.ajax(url));
    jsPromise.then(function(response) {
        allProfiles = response
        this.emitChange();
    });

    return allProfiles;
  }

// other methods omitted to save space
```

I should point out that your use of promises here is incorrect. The `then` function returns another promise, so you're setting `allProfiles` to a promise, not a collection. In the example above, we're returning the reference to the profile data, which will get updated after the AJAX call completes. Once the data is updated, the store emits a change to let all of its listeners know that they too should update.

In your component, you can set it up so it's listening to the `CHANGE_EVENT` on your `ProfileStore` such that it updates its state whenever the `ProfileStore`'s data changes. However, note that at the very beginning, the `allProfiles` data will be empty, so we'll need to convey to the user that we're loading the data:

```
var ProfileApp = React.createClass({

  updateAllProfiles: function () {
    this.setState({
      allProfiles: ProfileStore.getAll()
    });
  },

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      allProfiles: ProfileStore.getAll()
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    ProfileStore.addChangeListener(this.updateAllProfiles);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    ProfileStore.removeChangeListener(this.updateAllProfiles)
  },

  render: function () {
    var profiles;
    if (this.state.allProfiles) {
      // you'll need to figure out how you want to render the profiles
      // the line below will likely not be enough
      profiles = this.state.allProfiles;  
    } else {
      profiles = 'Loading...';
    }
    return <div id='profiles'>{profiles}</div>;
  }

});
```

I've made a VERY contrived example on JSFiddle. Due to the constraints of the environment, I had to come up with a couple of simulated hacks, but I hope your can tinker with the example and get a better feel for what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/berh6gxs/2/

I also glossed over a lot of details (e.g. you might want to implement a `shouldComponentUpdate` method on your `ProfileApp` component so it only re-renders when the data has actually changed), but I felt those kinds of details less important to answering the question at hand. I mention this because you won't be able to take what I've said here and immediately come up with a solution that works perfectly.

I'd also suggest looking into third-party implementations of Flux. Yahoo has come up with one that's pretty good: https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```javascript
jsPromise.then(function(response) {
    return response;
});
```

doesn't do what I think you think it does. It waits for `jsPromise` to resolve, calls the callback with the response, and whatever you return from the callback becomes the resolved value of a *new* promise that gets returned from `jsPromise.then`. Check out [this JavaScript Promises guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) for more information on how promises work.

As for your question: in short, you can't return a value from an asynchronous operation; you'll always have to resort to a callback. For example:

```javascript
var ProfileStore = merge(EventEmitter.prototype, {
  // getAll returns a Promise that resolves to all the profiles
  getAll: function() {
    var url = "..."
    return Promise.resolve($.ajax(url));
  },
  // ...
});

var ProfileApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      allProfiles: [] // initially we have no profiles
                      // could also have some "loading" sentinel, etc
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    // Then we ask for all the profiles and *asynchronously*
    // set the state so the component updates.
    ProfileStore.getAll().then(function(response) {
      this.setState({allProfiles: response});
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: In this example, how does the store know about the data returned by the ajax call (response object) ?

Comment: @nilgun I don't quite understand your question, but fisherwebdev's answer above may help